# Повторное воспроизводство цикла с измененным условием в Python

Tags: python, циклы

Прошу подсказать новичку, если не сложно)

Изучаю парсинг сайтов, столкнулся с задачей, простой, но уже неделю ломаю мозг)
Есть массив (параметры метода API, который вернет 1000 значений и занесет их в кортеж:

```
params2= params = {'group_id': 330777, 'sort': 'id_asc', 'city': 'Город', 'offset': 0, 'count': 1000}
```

Так как у сервера ограничения на 1000 запросов за раз, необходимо зациклить сбор, пока значение ключа "offset" не достигнет некоторой цифры. По завершении первого сбора и занесения значений в кортеж, значение "offset" нужно увеличить на 1000, и цикл должен повториться уже с увеличенным значением, и так до тех пор, пока "offset" не достигнет скажем 7000.

Как быть?

Comment: Дрбавте фрагмент кода, в котором у вас возникли затруднения.

Comment: Похоже на какой-то запрос api vk

Comment: В хороших API есть возможность манипуляции отдельно с id записей. Сформируйте список необходимых id сначала. Затем разбейте его на массивы по 1000 записей (рекурсия срезов `[:1000]`. Далее стучитесь с этим в API.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно вы о `VK-Api`, вот небольшой пример если я вас правильно понял:

```
in [30]: import vk

In [31]: def getmembers(session):
    ...:     max_offset = session.groups.getMembers(group_id=26667550)['count']
    ...:     result = list()
    ...:     for offset in range(0, max_offset, 1000):
    ...:         result.append(session.groups.getMembers(group_id=26667550, offset=offset))
    ...:     return result
    ...:

In [32]: def auth(login, password):
    ...:     return vk.API(vk.AuthSession(
    ...:                 app_id=6023569,
    ...:                 user_login=login,
    ...:                 user_password=password,
    ...:                 scope='groups'))
```

Использование:

```
In [33]: getmembers(auth('login', 'password'))
```

Comment: Да, это метод groups.getMembers. Но циклы в вашем примере понять не могу (нуб еще!). Вот мой код: r=requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers',params={'group_id':33064682, 'sort':'time_desk', 'offset':0, 'count':500}) - получил первую партию людей. Если не сложно, объясните на "счетных палочках", как циклически изменять значения ключа 'offset' с шагом в 1000 и последовательно заменять их в ссылке для нового обращения к серверу, и при этом результаты каждого нового обращения нужно добавлять в кортеж, пока 'offset' не превысит число подписчиков?

Comment: @Ewgensky добавил более понятный пример